# Placing Other Tkinter Objects in Front of Label Objects

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm new here, so forgive any glaring stackoverflow convention issues. I am working with tkinter, and I have placed images across my canvas using label objects. Now I would like to place other canvas objects (for instance, ovals) on top of the images, but I'm finding that the images always block the ovals. I have tried commands like tag_raise, but all to no avail. Is there some way I can get canvas objects to not be blocked by images? By the way, I need my images to be placed in specific locations and to have specific heights and widths. Also, I'm new to tkinter, so I would appreciate detail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally speaking you should be able to do what you describe. Please provide the simplest possible [mre] of it not working.

Comment: You cannot put other canvas objects over embedded widgets. You say you used labels to display images - are you aware that the canvas natively supports images without the use of labels?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @martineau got it, should I edit my question to include the code?

Comment: Yes, that's how to do it.

Comment: @BryanOakley do you mean create_image? Are you saying that if I create the image that way, I can place things over it? (I did try using that function as well, but I confess to not knowing how to change the width and height. Indeed, I copied and pasted a basic example from online and it didn't even work. I can include that in the question as well. Thanks for bearing with my beginner skills!)

Comment: @Damalone: yes, `create_image`. And yes, you can place things over images added to a canvas with `create_image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas documentation explicitly states that you cannot draw above embedded widgets:

*"Note: due to restrictions in the ways that windows are managed, it is not possible to draw other graphical items (such as lines and images) on top of window items. A window item always obscures any graphics that overlap it, regardless of their order in the display list."*

You can, however, add images to a canvas without using a `Label` widget. The canvas has a `create_image` method which can be used to add images directly to the canvas. When images are added in this way, other canvas items can be added on top.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(file="/tmp/image.png")
cx = image.width()//2
cy = image.height()//2

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="black", bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                   width=image.width(), height=image.height())
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.create_image(cx, cy, image=image)
canvas.create_oval(cx-20, cy-20, cx+20, cy+20, fill="red")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot, image overlaid with oval]

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can create the image from a PIL image (generated from Image.open)? I could save the PIL image as a new image in my computer, but I would need to generate thousands of images for what I am doing.

Comment: @Damalone: yes, you can use PIL to create the image objects.